# How to pass routing parameter to controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a Web API 4.6 which that needs routing/structural clean-up. Let's consider the following route configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BaseRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{source}/{sourceDocumentName}/{entity}/{projectNumber}/{action}/{outputType}"
        );
}
```

I would like `{sourceDocumentName}` to govern the controller selected and be passed to the constructor. So if `{sourceDocumentName} == "Purchase" || "Order"` it would resolve to `RequisitionController(sourceDocumentName)` and pass the parameter into the constructor.

Comment: What is the actual requirement that  you need to do this? How does it help you to pass route value to the controller constructor?

Comment: Using asp.net "out of the box" it would mean I would have to create multiple controllers with the same code. `PurchaseController` would be the same as `OrderController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Why does it have to actually be passed into the constructor? As a route value, you can already access it any time via: `RouteData.Values`.
2. You can still use multiple controllers and just have them inherit from a base controller, if that much of the logic is shared.

Comment: 1. That solves how to use that route value as a parameter but not how to utilize it to map to a specific controller.

Comment: 2. I'm actually doing that right now. Note that you have to make your own one line  custom routing provider for it to resolve to the derived class name instead of the base class name. The reason why I'm not satisfied with that is because I've ran into problems overwriting routes on action methods.

Comment: Have you considered attribute routing? Probably would make your life easier.

Comment: I have attribute routing in one controller (I know, a mess), was having problems making it work with convention-based routing (possibly due to the custom routing provider. Removing the convention-based routing would make the code more "wet" then I'd like and difficult to maintain.

Comment: So in effect this answer could work hence upvoting, but @Jinish answer has better separation of responsibilities so currently testing that approach.

Comment: After not being able to get the custom `IControllerFactory` I re-visited the attribute routing approach and it worked this time around and now the help xml is able to discover all end-points. Clarification: just throw a`[RoutePrefix("")]` into the derived class and keep any shared implementation in the base class with attribute routing.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to understand is the Mvc request pipeline really. When a request comes in, the Route Table i.e. `MvcRouteHandler` executes and gets an instance of the `MvcHttpHandler` that basically initializes the controller that needs to be mapped based on the route data with the help of `ControllerFactory`.

So essentially what you are looking at is to have a custom implementation of your own `IControllerFactory` so be able to tap into this request pipeline.

Comment: For some reason my custom IControllerFactory was not being called after first request so I was unable to get it working. Not many examples on how to out there but [here](http://www.jomendez.com/2016/01/20/how-to-create-custom-controller-factory-asp-net/) is one.